# Phonegap / Cordova include external src without http / https

Tags: android, http, mobile, plugins, cordova

So here it is, I'm starting a Phonegap app and would like to use a given library. In the library code it tries to reach some URL with this form :

```
//img.site.com/given_img.png
```

without http or https at the beginning so it will adapt nicely. But when launching the app on my phone I see it tries to reach :

```
file://img.site.com/given_img.png
```

Not http or https... But file protocol. Obviously it fails to load...

Anyone knows how to deal with this ?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, after researching this for some time... Currently there is no solution out of the box. You have to check the code with JS and force add the wanted protocol into it before execution. I simply changed the way I wanted to do things and avoided that kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind having `src="//domain.com/some/pic"` is so that the browser will request those assets with the protocol matching **your website**, meaning, if your website is running on `http` - it will request the picture over `http`, vs if your website is running on `https` it will request the image with `https://`.

@Jeremy is right, there's no option at the moment. 
But you can take the protocol matching your website with `var protocol = window.location.protocol` and use that in your `src={{ protocol + image }}`

This is to prevent from writing hard-coded `http / https` and mix secure with non-secure content in your website which causes errors to jump like `"This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items"`